# Search method of the Office Javascript API throws an InvalidArgument Exception

Tags: javascript, ms-office

I´m trying to do a search in a word document in the next way:

```js
var searchResults = context.document.body.search(CitaTo , {matchCase:false});
```

When CitaTo contains a text larger than 255 characters, an InvalidArgument Exception is thrown. It works fine with shorter texts. The issue only occurs when using Word 2016, but not with Word online.

I have been looking for information about this limitation with no results. Neither in the  at [Office Javascript API specification](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/searchoptions).

Does anyone know anything about this limitation or any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation in Ms. Word itself, for Desktop and Mac both. You cannot search for a search string with characters more than 255.
There is an alternative workaround that you can do. You can split the search string and search each splitted text seperately and then use Range.extendTo() to merge the ranges.